# don't call connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to download some file from some server. Functionality that download file is working in Thread. So, you can see it here:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileDataBaseURL];
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileDataBaseEnc contents:nil attributes:nil];
    self._handleDataBaseEnc = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:fileDataBaseEnc];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

}
```

also I have  functions:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_handleDataBaseEnc seekToEndOfFile];

    NSMutableData *receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    [_handleDataBaseEnc writeData:receivedData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [_handleDataBaseEnc closeFile];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     [_handleDataBaseEnc closeFile];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
 }
```

**QUESTIONS**

**Why do these three functions don't work? it doesn't call, never.**

**How can i fix it?**

Comment: Why do these last three functions don't work? it doesn't call, never.

Comment: Did you make sure "theConnection" isn't nil and that the request goes out?

Comment: I did it. theConnection not equal nil.

Comment: Can you post the URL you're using?

Comment: Also, just making sure - all the delegate functions are defined within the same class implementation, right?

Comment: BTW - These situations normally occur when you're trying to issue the request on a thread other than the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Art**'s anwer in here:[NSURLConnection delegate methods are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787170/nsurlconnection-delegate-methods-are-not-called/5787223#5787223)

*Try running the operation on main thread:*

```
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                initWithRequest:request
                                       delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                      forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the posted code giving a clue why the delegate methods aren't being called.   The one thing I notice about them is that they aren't doing anything special.  How about running the connection in a single line with:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

Call that right after theConnection is instantiated.