# iOS : Progress view for File Uploading to server?

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I want to implement Progress view for File Uploading to the server, can any one guide me with example

if i use

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   
   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite    {

    float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
    float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"progress/total %f",progress/total);
}
```

it is not called while upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Improve You Question. What i understand form it here is the base Idea.

1. `Upload File On Server`

   So please review this answer for idea of [uploading an file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434537/post-image-to-server-in-iphone/16434601#16434601)
2. `Show ProgressView`

   First You need to add `progressView` in `UI Thread` and then create another thread for communicating with server that thread will responsible for uploading file and with base idea callback as response from server with in `UI Thread` and remove `progressView`.

like review this code

```
dispatch_queue_t anotherThreadQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
//add progress view here...
dispatch_async(anotherThreadQueue, ^{
        //then upload file here....
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // UI Thread update View ( remove progressView)
      });
 });
```

or for showing the progress for uploading file you can use
`connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` as you using `NSURLConnection`

Comment: i completed uploading file on server, if i implement didSendBodyData for NSURLConnection, its not called properly?

Comment: `didSendBodyData` called when the request has a body data like in `POST`. are you using `GET` ?

Comment: as the process says we can track the uploading process using `didSendBodyData` now you need to track on your side as `delegates` or minor issue will be there.

Comment: i m using NSURLConnectionDelegate in .h ? is that fine?

Comment: tried that too but no effect on **didSendBodyData**

Comment: `NSURLConnection *conenction = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];` and ensure `< NSURLConnectionDataDelegate >`

Comment: yes already done those things, But still no effect on delegate

Comment: Finally i got it :) this post helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787170/nsurlconnection-delegate-methods-are-not-called

Comment: so what was the problem ?

Comment: i missed to set [connection start];

Comment: Oh :) happen sometime... BTW good luck and for good programming habit review your code line by line.